# Meteor full page refresh on load more button ( iron-router )

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, meteor, iron-router

My Meteor app seems to be refreshing on a new route, I added iron-router-progress as I'm following the Discover Meteor.

Heres the URL - http://thusstyles.meteor.com/

Github URL - github.com/ThusStyles/diccoverMeteor

Discover Meteor URL - http://meteor-book-chapter12-5.meteor.com/

Mine seems to jump to the top when the load more button is clicked.

Comment: code example please. Sounds like you need to do preventDefault or something on that link

Comment: same happens with me as well

Comment: The page jump is talked about in the comments [here](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commit/chapter12-5). Apparently this is a known issue but Tom is uncertain why. Your app doesn't appear to be doing a refresh - at least not in my browser.

Comment: So should I use version 0.7.0 of iron-router then?

Comment: FIXED - By using 0.7.0 version of iron-router

Comment: i have the same problem but i do not see the iron-router 0.7.0 version, the earliest version seems like 0.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use **waitOn** instead of **subscriptions**. waitOn will try to render the loading template, while subscriptions will still subscribe but won't trigger the loading template, thus not cause the flickering.

However, this will also render the page before the subscriptions are ready. Therefore you need to keep keep track of the ready-state for the subscriptions. See example for Discover Meteor. Note that data is returning this.postsSub.ready, which is set under subscriptions.

```
PostsListController = RouteController.extend({
template: 'postsList',
increment: 5,
postsLimit: function() {
return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment;
},
findOptions: function() {
return {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: this.postsLimit()};
},
subscriptions: function() {
this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.findOptions());
},
posts: function() {
return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
},
data: function() {
var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.postsLimit();
var nextPath = this.route.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increm
ent});
return {
posts: this.posts(),
ready: this.postsSub.ready,
nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
};
}
});
```

See full example on GitHub:
https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commit/chapter12-5